# d3.js: barchart with time series - 1 tick & bar per date, rounding numbers

Tags: d3.js, axis-labels

Still new to D3.js... this is my second chart.

I'm trying to build a fairly straightforward bar/column chart with dates on the x-axis, and a simple count on the y-axis. I'm currently trying to get the axis right, and having a few issues:

1. **How do I get one tick (and one bar) per day/date** (chart will cover a 30 day period)
2. **How do I get the y-axis ticks to be whole numbers** (currently giving me ~ 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, etc)
3. **How do I get the tick labels to respond to text-anchor... either start or end?**

I've created a jsbin to illustrate: http://jsbin.com/axafid/4/

Here's my data and code so far (partially based on this tutorial: http://bl.ocks.org/phoebebright/3061203)

```
    var testData = [
        {
            date: "2013-06-25",
            programs: 1
        },
        {
            date: "2013-06-26",
            programs: 2
        },
        {
            date: "2013-06-27",
            programs: 3
        },
        {
            date: "2013-06-28",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-06-29",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-06-30",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-01",
            programs: 1
        },

        {
            date: "2013-07-02",
            programs: 3,
            premiums: 9000
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-03",
            programs: 1
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-04",
            programs: 4
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-05",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-06",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-07",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-08",
            programs: 1
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-09",
            programs: 2
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-10",
            programs: 2
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-11",
            programs: 4
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-12",
            programs: 4
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-13",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-14",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-15",
            programs: 2
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-16",
            programs: 2
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-17",
            programs: 1
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-18",
            programs: 5
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-19",
            programs: 1
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-20",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-21",
            programs: 0
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-22",
            programs: 3
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-23",
            programs: 3
        },
        {
            date: "2013-07-24",
            programs: 3
        }
]
```

and my javascript:

```
function renderGraph(){

        var margin = {top: 20, right: 16, bottom: 32, left: 64},// space around the chart, not including labels
            width = (mainWidth() - margin.left - margin.right),   // width of svg
            height = 400,  // height of svg
            parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%d").parse;

        var data = testData;

        var x_domain = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }),
            y_domain = [0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.programs; })]


        // display date format
        var  date_format = d3.time.format("%d %b");

        // create an svg container
        var vis = d3.select("#programs-renewing-graph")
                .append("svg:svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

        // define the y scale  (vertical)
        var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain(y_domain).nice()   // make axis end in round number
            .range([height - margin.top, margin.bottom]);// map these to the chart height, less padding.

        var xScale = d3.time.scale()
            .domain(x_domain)
            .range([32, width - margin.right]);

        // define the y axis
        var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient("left")
            .scale(yScale);

        // define the x axis
        var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
            .orient("bottom")
            .scale(xScale)
            .tickFormat(date_format);

        // draw y axis with labels and move in from the sides by the amount of padding
        vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+",0)")
            .call(yAxis);

        // draw x axis with labels and move to the bottom of the chart area
        vis.append("g")
            .attr("class", "xaxis axis")  // two classes, one for css formatting, one for selection below
            .attr("transform", "translate(" +margin.left+ "," + (height - margin.top) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can specify the number of ticks like this:

   ```
   // define the x axis
   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .orient("bottom")
       .scale(xScale)
       .ticks(d3.time.days(x_domain[0], x_domain[1]).length)
       .tickFormat(date_format);
   ```

   Specify the number of ticks as the number of days in the domain of the axis.
2. Same as 1. but using whole numbers:

   ```
   // define the y axis
   var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
       .orient("left")
       .ticks(d3.range(y_domain[0], y_domain[1], 1).length)
       .scale(yScale);
   ```

   Specify the number of ticks to be the length of the range of the domain in whole numbers.
3. You can access and change the tick labels by selecting them after creating them with the axis generator like this:

   ```
   vis.append("g")
       .attr("class", "axis")
       .attr("transform", "translate("+margin.left+"," + margin.top + ")")
       .call(yAxis)
       .selectAll('text')
         .style('text-anchor','middle');
   ```

   Here the text-anchor style is changed from the default 'end' to 'middle'.

Here's a modified jsbin with the above changes and with the declaration of the axes cleaned up a bit: http://jsbin.com/axafid/9/edit

Comment: That works! Just to help me understand, in your #2, if the data did have fractional numbers like "5.3", what part of the definition is rounding the number to "5"?

Comment: OK - I think I see. From the API:  d3.range([start, ]stop[, step]) Since we've set the step to 1, the ticks will increase in whole number increments of 1.

Comment: That's right, you don't actually round the number.  Since you already set the range on the axis, you just tell d3 how many ticks to show... The step of 1 is the default, so you don't really need to specify it in this case.